# What are the variants of the J-11 still used by China?

Tags: su-27

The J-11A Flanker-B+ is a Chinese licensed copy of the Su-27SK from Russia (Unlike the J-11B which wasn't). So do the PLAAF still use the J-11A (If so, with AL-31s or WS-10s?)

Comment: The J-11A was not a licensed copy, it was a joint assembly project. China tried to sell internationally but the engine performance leaves much to be desired. The J-11B is an illegal copy of the -11A, in keeping with China's bad habits of stealing IP from other countries.

Comment: @JuanJimenez  J-11 was a licensed copy of Su-27SK that was divided into two parts. Part A was to assemble locally with Russian parts, which last from 1996 to 2007 (first deliver of parts in 1996, first flight in 1998). Part B was to use locally made parts and started as soon as technical materials was received. The first B model took flight in 2003 and is in production till this day. If B were an illegal copy why would Russia have supplied engines and other parts for it for 20+ years?

Comment: @user3528438 It's what happens when you get caught making illegal copies. You ask for forgiveness after the fact and pay a license fee. Had China had the ability to produce good engines that would probably not have happened.

Comment: @JuanJimenez If it's all that simple then I'll start making illegal copies of everything myself.

Comment: @user3528438 Knock yourself out, but make sure you lawyer up first.

Answer (score 0):

The PLAAF still uses the J-11A. [Some J-11As received some new missile approach warning systems and some upgrades to the fire-control system back in 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222095700/http://www.janes.com/article/49903/images-suggest-upgrades-to-china-s-early-series-j-11s) but since the J-11A is just a Su-27 assembled in China, even the upgraded J-11As probably still use the AL-31 engine.

Edit: [The first 100 J-11s built use the AL-31, but the rest use the WS-10A.](http://www.military-today.com/aircraft/j11.htm)

Comment: Oh, ok. So are they still unable to carry the PL-8 and PL-12 Air-to-Air missiles?

Comment: Correct, it seems that they're still limited to R-77s and PL-10s.

Comment: So they were changed to carry PL-10s but not PL-8s or PL-12s?

Comment: As far as the article states, that's precisely the case. China's J-11As can't carry PL-8s or PL-12s, at least for now. The upgrades only appear to have added the ability to carry PL-10s and R-77s.

Comment: So do the Chinese still use the AA-11 Archer AAM or has it been totally replaced by the PL-10?

Comment: China still uses the AA-11 / R-73, although it's not compatible with the J-15, J-16 or J-20 (The J-10, Su-27 / J-11A, and Su-35 can use them) so they might be planning on retiring it at some point.

Comment: Okay, so they literally still use the old cockpit of the Su-27SK? If so that's interesting.

Comment: The J-11As were literally just Su-27SKs sold to China as kits. Given that the J-11B is a reverse-engineered version of the J-11A / Su-27SK, it wouldn't be that surprising if China reused the Su-27SK cockpit.

Comment: We know they reused it (Deka Ironworks Simulations found that out for DCS World) but do they still use the same cockpit?

Comment: The J-11B and J-11D have a glass cockpit, which the J-11A doesn't have. Other than this and some improved subsystems, the cockpit is probably _still_ the same.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's very interesting.